# Android Studio waiting for build to finish (activity_home_drawer.xml)

Tags: android-studio

I've started to work with Android Studio. I tried to open `activity_home_drawer.xml` file, but I can only see

```
waiting for build to finish..
```

Can any one help me?

I already tried clean project and re build, but not success I had tried in so many ways what are explained in other StackOverflow question. but I still can't find a solution for this.

Comment: What are the configurations of your system?

Comment: first of all i would like to apology from you. i am new to android studio. hence i could not understand that what you are ask in above (configuration)

Comment: I am asking about `RAM` and `Processor` of your CPU.

Comment: RAM is 4GB and processor is i3(7th generation)

Comment: is able to make an affect by RAM or processor to such problem

Comment: Yes, if these are low, then Android-Studio can take up much more time to finish build, but in your case they seems like good.

Comment: the message of "waiting for build to finish...."  is in a non terminal loop. it not finish yet

Comment: How many processes are running? You can see them in the bottom. like 2 processes running

Comment: none of one  running in here

Comment: Then, at top click `build` and then click `build project`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gradle needs to re-sync. Go do gradle and make some changes, e.x  add comment. There will be a yellow Sync now button on right corner. Click on that, it should fix it

Comment: dear sir/ madam i already do this things. but not get favorable solution

Comment: I don't know, It happens me sometimes and fix it just like this